# Telegram Webhook is not getting supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to setup Webhook in my telegram Bot app but the issue is when I am removing the polling:true value its not working, after any commands no response is coming.

```
export class UserWorker {
  private bot: TelegramBot;
  private databaseService: DatabaseService;
  private notificationService: TelegramNotificationService;
  private userService: TelegramUserService;

  constructor(telegramBotToken: string, webhookUrl: string) {
    this.bot = new TelegramBot(telegramBotToken, { polling: true});

    this.setUpExpress(telegramBotToken);

    this.setWebHook(webhookUrl, telegramBotToken);

    this.databaseService = DatabaseProvider.createService();
    this.notificationService = NotificationProvider.createService(
      this.bot,
      this.databaseService,
    );
    this.userService = UserServiceProvider.createService(
      this.bot,
      this.databaseService
    );
    this.userService.init();
    this.notificationService.init();
  }

  private setUpExpress(telegramBotToken: string) {
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Express server is listening on ${port}`);
    });

    app.post(`bot${telegramBotToken}`, (req:any, res:any) => {
      try {
        this.bot.processUpdate(req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
      } 
      catch(error) {
        console.log('Error in Processing Request:', error)
      }
    });
  }

  private async setWebHook(webhookUrl: string, telegramBotToken: string) {
    try {
      const webhookInfo = await this.bot.getWebHookInfo();
      if (webhookInfo.url === webhookUrl) {
        console.log('Webhook is already set to the correct URL');
        return;
      }
  
      await this.bot.setWebHook('');
      console.log('Existing webhook removed');
  
      const fullWebhookUrl = encodeURI(`${webhookUrl}/bot${telegramBotToken}`);
      await this.bot.setWebHook(fullWebhookUrl);
      console.log('Webhook is set', fullWebhookUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in setting webhook:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

After removing the { polling: true } no command is listen by the Telegram bot and its working along only with { polling: true } command I setup the entire Webhook and webhook url is also active, since the webhook in the telegram bot is more efficient how can I get rid of this polling: true in my code